# Is there a clear specification when a review item is either 'requires editing' or 'unsalvageable'?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

I've just failed my first 'Review Triage' review task. Before I reviewed the item, I looked in the Help Center to get a hint when I should set 'requires editing' or 'unsalvageable'. I haven't found anything there.

So I decided that the clear spam post should have 'requires editing', because someone has to tag it as spam. But I can see that also the other tag make sense.

Have I simply overseen a help file or a Meta Stack Overflow question? If not, wouldn't it be nice to have a better explanation somewhere which explains better how to tag this review task, maybe with some good examples (due to the fact that I've failed there are examples, already)?

**EDIT**

There was indeed a good link here: [Is there a guide for triage?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-triage) (thx to DavidPostill).

The problem came up, because it was not clear for me that a modal appears with more options after clicking on 'unsalvageable'. 'The additional 'skip' and 'looks ok' buttons lead the user to the opinion that there is a one-click solution. Maybe there could be done some improvements in the UX. But the question itself is well answered now, imo.

Comment: You don't edit spam. You flag it as spam.

Comment: Sure, normally I would flag this question as spam. But in the review view I was asked how to classify them with given possibilites.

Comment: Needs a little cleaning up (spelling, grammar, formatting) but is fundamentally on-topic and contains the appropriate information: *requires editing*. Unclear, needs further input **from the OP** (so can't be edited by the community) or is off-topic: *unsalvageable*. Spam: *flag as spam*.

Comment: Thx, jonrsharpe. You're right. But my problem was a step before which was hard to see. It was at least a UX problem. I've edited my question.

Comment: You should pretty much never use [Requires Editing].

Comment: @TinyGiant: If the question has a terrible title, amazingly bad formatting, or abominable tags, it requires editing. If there's stuff in the comments or links to code or screenshots that need to be pulled in, it requires editing. And so on.

Comment: @NathanTuggy If it should be closed, and cannot be edited to be on-topic by the community even if it also has any of those other problems, it is unsalvageable. If it is an on-topic question that just so happens to have some major issues that can all be fixed by the community, then it requires editing.

Comment: @TinyGiant: True enough. (I did include all that in the rather verbose faq-proposed the answer links to.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spam questions (and answers) should not be edited, they should be flagged as "Spam"

If you are in the Triage review queue:

Click "Unsalvageable" > Select "Spam" > Click "Flag Question"

[image]

See [Is there a guide for the Triage queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-triage) for more information.